How to use/get props in entry file (index.js)
Below is the boiler plate code generated when using React 18.
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
reportWebVitals();

Here, I want to use props field. Like in previous React version it creates something like
export default function main({props}) { ...
but in React 18 it has been changed. Now, I want to use props as I am getting some data in it. How can I do that ??
Suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks

Hi, do you mean that you need props in the index.js file or in the App component? I doubt that you could pass props in the index.js file before. Index.js file is the entry point of the application, how could you do that before?

Giving a little context that I am using React with some other environment which is Liferay. In React 17 entry file (index.js) looks like this.
export default function main(params) {    ReactDOM.render(   <AppComponent     portletNamespace={params.portletNamespace}     contextPath={params.contextPath}    portletElementId={params.portletElementId}    configuration={params.configuration}    />,    document.getElementById(params.portletElementId)  ); }
Now, I am receiving properties inherently and just accessing through props. But in React 18 the code structure has been changed.

I want something like this in React version 18

Nothing stops you from wrapping your code in a function and exporting it like in the example you provided

@Konrad When I do that it renders nothing. Do i need to add something in Package.json file??
